# Ejs rendered vars are undefined

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm writing my first webb ap with nodejs and express, using ejs templates.
now when I'm rendering the html files it all works fine, but when I try to render the files with parameters, it seems like the rendered ejs template can't find the parameters I've sent to it.

here is my file structure :

```
project/
  Views/
    index.ejs
    login.ejs
  public/
    all the css files ..
  node_modules/
  server.js
```

and here is my server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY',resave: false, saveUninitialized: false})); // change the secret to safer one
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == undefined) {
        // if user is not logged-in redirect back to login page //
        res.render('login');
    } else {
        console.log(req.session.user);
        res.render('index', {username:req.session.user});
    }
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});


app.listen(8080);
console.log('port: 8080');
```

and here is my index.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Dashboard</title>

  </head>

  <body>

     <div><%= username %></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and for some reason whenever I try to access index.ejs, it returnes an error - 
"username is not defined"

any idea what I'm doing wrong? the examples online looks exactly the same

thanks !

after Fadi Bitar answered this is how my server get event looks like and it's stil won't work:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == undefined) {
        // if user is not logged-in redirect back to login page //
        res.render('login',{username:req.session.user});
    } else {
        console.log(req.session.user);
        res.render('index', {username:req.session.user});
    }
});

// about page
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login',{username:req.session.user});
});
```

Comment: Looks okay? You tried with a string just to check that the  `render` call is the issue, as in `res.render('index', {username:'Elion'});`

Comment: yea, tried also to put a string in a var and send the var to the render as in:
var bla = "text";
res.render('index', {username:bla});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the initial code, it should work... Without seeing it my guess is that you are trying to echo `<%=username%>` in login.ejs.

Your updated code has a couple of points where you're using a variable that doesn't exist.

```
if (req.session.user == undefined) {
    res.render('login',{username:req.session.user});
}
```

Here you're saying 'if req.session.user is undefined, set username to req.session.user' (undefined).

Then this bit does the same..

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login',{username:req.session.user});
});
```

I assume here that when you go to /login req.session.user is not set, so that's why that errors...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the "username" variable in your get function.

Make sure you do:
    res.render('/', {username: "example username"});

Comment: well, I double checked and added more declerations of "username" sent to render, and still nothing. look at my post, I added my new code in the bottom of it.